# C# Getting errors on setting Spellcheck.IsEnabled when embedding WPF

Tags: c#

So, in my C# project i am embedding a WPF richtextbox for spellcheck,
This works perfectly, but in Visual Studio Enterprise, when setting the SpellCheck.IsEnabled i get 6 errors. And even with these errors it still works and the spellcheck works fine. (Obviously when not setting SpellCheck.IsEnabled it does not work)

(The errors only show up in the Visual Studio debug error console and not in the program itself as a regular Exception)

So

I embed a WPF RichTextBox using:

```
System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox omschrijving = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();
```

And i set the SpellCheck like

```
omschrijving.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

With this i get the following errors:

```
1:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging  1.32s       [6252] Main Thread 

2:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging  1.32s       [6252] Main Thread 

3:

Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.") Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging    1.32s       [6252] Main Thread 

4:

Exception caught: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.") Exception caught: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging    1.32s       [6252] Main Thread 

5:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging  1.32s       [6252] Main Thread 

6:

Exception caught: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Exception caught: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationFramework.dll ("De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging  1.32s       [6252] Main Thread
```

I tried to manually set the language

```
omschrijving.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-us");
```

And i tried to set the value in after the Form_Load

But neither worked, and im quite confused what's going on here.

Comment: There is a rather large chunk of C++ code underneath this that you can't see.  That code is unhappy about *something*, all you know is that it throws a hissy-fit with an E_INVALIDARG error code.  Not necessarily fatal, but if you have trouble with it not marking words correctly or just not seeing spelling errors at all then you may need to add the required language pack.  Do make sure you don't run this code in a worker thread btw.

Comment: It's not about the language check, the spelling checks works totally fine. With or without setting it. So that's quite odd